# How to get the 'nose' command to work on OS X?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7, terminal

```
Installing collected packages: nose

Could not install packages due to an error.
```

> EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose' Consider using the `--user`
>   option or check the permissions.

Comment: how you are installing 'nose'?, command?

Comment: (Aside: I edited this to merge the two parts of the error, and to reduce the pleading in the title. That was helpful to getting an answer, even if it was still not very clear. I tend to recommend that you just accept edits from experienced users, on the basis their version probably is clearer).

Comment: (It looks like this question has been abandoned without requested clarifications).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use pip to install your nose package? If so, try upgrading the pip first.Then try,

```
pip install nose
```

Please note that nose has been in maintenance mode for couple of years now. On the installation page, there are three ways mentioned to install nose. Have you tried all three? Please mention using what you are facing this error. Also, it's better to have the installation of packages in virtual env rather than in your main installation of python.

Comment: yeah i face this error whenever i want to install a package, and i did upgrade the pip, but this error keep showing